# Macro to cycle through and allocate data to members of structs incorrectly recognises struct member as pointer

Tags: c, macros, struct, cycle, type-conversion

My problem is that atoi is converting a string's hexadecimal memory address to decimal, instead of what's contained within the string. It is doing this during a macro. Why is it interpreting struct->member as a pointer, when the macro definition makes it an int? Pseudocode below:

```
if (struct.member == int)? struct.member = atoi(data) : struct.member = data;
```

The aim of this section of the program is to retrieve data from a .csv file containing information about a structs attributes. I can take in an "id" and store each cells string into an array of strings (csvRowSplit).

However, I then want to transfer the contents of the array to a structure that contains different data types (a method that I want to use to retrieve players saved attributes, attack methods, shop items etc.). It's easy to hard code:

```
opponent->att = atoi(csvSplitRow[0]);
opponent->= atoi(csvSplitRow[1]);
opponent->hitpoints = atoi(csvSplitRow[2]);
opponent->description = csvSplitRow[3]);
```

However this clutters with more struct members and is not very flexible or reproducible.

I have defined a macro to cycle through the elements of a structure, and pair up the csvSplitRow[] to the variables, converting if required with atoi.

```
#define X_FIELDS \
    X(char*, description, "%s") \
    X(int, xpreward, "%d") \
    X(int, att, "%d") \
    /* ... */
    X(int, crit, "%d")

typedef struct
{
    #define X(type, name, format) type name;
        X_FIELDS
    #undef
}

void update_opp(char** csvSplitRow, opp* opponent)
{
    int i = 0;
    #define X(type, name, format) \
        if (strcmp(format, "%d") == 0) \          // if an int, convert it
            opponent->name = atoi(csvSplitRow[i]); \
        else \                                    // otherwise put it straight in
            opponent->name = csvSplitRow[i]; \
        i++;
    X_FIELDS
    #undef X
}
```

The assignment directly to the string members work (ie. no conversion), but atoi results in a conversion of the hexadecimal memory address to an integer, instead of the string it's pointing to.

```
// before conversion
csvRowSplit[1] == 0x501150 "20"

// practice
atoi(csvRowSplit[1]) == 20

// after conversion and storing in struct int member
opponent->xpreward = atoi(csvSplitRow[1]);
opponent->xpreward == 5247312           // the decimal equivalent of 0x501150
```

I don't know what I can do now, other than hard code each time I want to match up a parsed line of csv with a structure. Please help!

EDIT:
I get a compile time error with -Werror:

```
error: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Werror]
```

Error is within the macro of the update_opp function. However, I know it's not a pointer because I defined it to be an int earlier? So why isn't it recognizing that? and I can't cast it, so what can I do?

Comment: Are you compiling with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`?  If not, give it a try.

Comment: Thanks, came up with lots of stuff! Will work on it and report back in a bit.

Comment: Why are the `atoi(` calls missing their closing `)`?

Comment: Sorry I rushed that, it was just to show what I was trying to avoid, it's not in the code. The problem seems to be with the macro definition: is it interpreting the struct member as a pointer when it shouldn't? How do I correct that?

Comment: Since `atoi()` only handles decimal conversions, you can't use it to convert hexadecimal; if the values are prefixed `0x`, you'll always get zero from `atoi()`; if not, the string will be treated as a decimal number.  Use `strtol()` et al for hexadecimal conversions.

Comment: I don't want the hexadecimal conversion- I'm passing `atoi()` the address to a string I want to convert to a decimal number. The current member of the struct equals the return value (as long as the `if (int)` condition is met. Somewhere in that, the current struct member end result is a converted hexadecimal memory address! I think this is because the struct member is being recognised as a pointer, when it shouldn't be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this code:

```
#define X(type, name, format) \
    if (strcmp(format, "%d") == 0) \          // if an int, convert it
        opponent->name = atoi(csvSplitRow[i]); \
    else \                                    // otherwise put it straight in
        opponent->name = csvSplitRow[i]; \
    i++;
```

For any given attribute name (`att` say), you get:

```
    if (strcmp("%d", "%d") == 0)
        opponent->att = atoi(csvSplitRow[i]);
    else
        opponent->att = csvSplitRow[i];
    i++;
```

Except that it is all on one line.  But, the key point is that you either assign an `int` (from `atoi()`) to a string or you assign a string to an `int` in every invocation, and one of those two is wrong.  The code has to be correct before it is optimized.

How to fix?  That's tricky.  I think I'd probably use something like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define CVT_INT(str)    atoi(str)
#define CVT_STR(str)    str

#define X_FIELDS \
    X(char*, description, "%s", CVT_STR) \
    X(int, xpreward, "%d", CVT_INT) \
    X(int, att, "%d", CVT_INT) \
    /* ... */ \
    X(int, crit, "%d", CVT_INT)

typedef struct opp
{
#define X(type, name, format, converter) type name;
    X_FIELDS
#undef X
} opp;

extern void update_opp(char** csvSplitRow, opp* opponent);

void update_opp(char** csvSplitRow, opp* opponent)
{
    int i = 0;

#define X(type, name, format, converter) \
    opponent->name = converter(csvSplitRow[i++]);

    X_FIELDS

#undef X
}
```

This compiles without warnings under very stringent compiler flags:

```
gcc -pedantic -g -std=c99 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes \
    -Wold-style-definition -c xm.c
```

The `CVT_INT` and `CVT_STR` macros could be redefined when required to do other things.

---

An alternative version of the code exploits `CVT_INT` and `CVT_STR` (renamed to `X_INT` and `X_STR`) more extensively:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

#define X_FIELDS \
    X(X_STR, description) \
    X(X_INT, xpreward) \
    X(X_INT, att) \
    /* ... */ \
    X(X_INT, crit)

typedef struct opp
{
#define X_INT char *
#define X_STR int
#define X(code, name) code name;
    X_FIELDS
#undef X
#undef X_INT
#undef X_STR
} opp;

extern void update_opp(char** csvSplitRow, opp* opponent);

void update_opp(char** csvSplitRow, opp* opponent)
{
    int i = 0;

#define X_INT(str)    atoi(str)
#define X_STR(str)    str
#define X(converter, name) \
    opponent->name =  converter(csvSplitRow[i++]);

    X_FIELDS

#undef X
#undef X_INT
#undef X_STR
}
```

I'm not 100% convinced this is better because of the multiple `#define` and `#undef` operations, but it is more nearly minimal in some respects (it doesn't need the `"%d"` vs `"%s"` fields, for example — at least, not in the code shown).

Comment: Thank you very much for your time to redesign my code so elegantly! I had forgotten I could include the `i++` within the array. Hopefully this will help others in a similar situation.Just to clarify: is the reason my implementation didn't work because of the "laws" of macros? So instead of skipping the appropriate lines of the if/else clause, it actually tested each one?

Comment: I'm not sure it is the 'laws of macros' so much as the 'laws of valid C', but the problem was that both the `if` and the `else` clause had to be compiled (and correct) before the optimizer could kick in and decide that the incorrect one wasn't wanted.

Comment: Ok thank you, I think I understand now: in order to avoid the compiler collision, you go outside of the flawed macro and compile the decision in a separate place, allowing the correct return type.

Format `"d"` and `"s"` can be omitted now, unless using `printf()` statements to make the code even cleaner.

Comment: Yes, unless you have a need to provide format specifiers, you don't need the `%d`.  Indeed, I'll add a possibly more streamlined version of the macros...it isn't completely clear that it's better because of the number of `#undef` lines, but it does use a simpler X macro with just two arguments.